# Distribute a function for QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-expression

I have written an expression to use in the field calculator that is to be used by a number of other users. In [Providing QGIS expression within a plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352787/providing-qgis-expression-within-a-plugin?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.7318) I was told how to distribute an expression (or a set of expressions) with a plugin, but in this case, I just need the expression, no user interface or other code.

To distribute it should I write a minimal plugin that just installs the file with the expression, or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I distribute my [OS Grid reference functions](https://github.com/ianturton/osgridref) via a plugin and it works very well.